# Checking if input type file multiple is empty in php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to check if an input type file with an attribute of multiple is empty, I've tried to check if count is equal to 0 i.e `if(count($_FILES['file'])){}` but it's not  working because even an empty array has a count of 5(the number I got when I echoed out the count), I have also tried using the empty function i.e `if(empty($_FILES['file'])){}` not also working, please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should count a info directive of the files instead of counting the file entry for the input name. Once you have multiple files being uploaded the arrays of the info directives extends to having multiple entries at all info directives at the input named entry.

```
if ( isset($_FILES['file'] && count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0 ) {
  // ...
}
```

Or with PHP 7.x:

```
if ( count($_FILES['file']['name'] ?? []) > 0 ) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but it still doesn't successfully check if it's empty

Comment: Well, i do not know your full code in detail. And my crystal ball is currently installing updates. So, it would be wisely to provide more code to extend the analysis of your issue towards it's real implementation.